# Copy files with specific header

Tags: files, find, cp, cat

How can I copy files with a contition that:

> the file content starts with Ascii `UnityFS5`

?

I think I have to join commands `cp`, `find`, `cat` and `grep` but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Find those files in one directory? Recursively?

Comment: @Freddy In one directory, in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy regular files (excluding hidden dot files) in your current directory starting with `UnityFS5`, you could use:

```
for file in *; do
  if [ -f "$file" ] && [ "$(head -c 8 "$file")" = "UnityFS5" ]; then
    cp "$file" /path/to/destination/
  fi
done
```

Comment: Maybe I should study bash script more!